# how to deal huge amounts of data,such as grouping operation?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, group-by

If a table has Hundreds of millions data,how to do grouping operation in SQL Server 2008?

who can gave me some suggestion?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If a table has Hundreds of millions data,how to do grouping operation in SQL Server 2008?

Misunderstandings.

- Hundreds of millions = small. I know a table we work on my probject tha gros around 60 million per day, and I have a data set that gros 600 million entries per day.
- SQL has grouping operations, you know.

Now, you state "entity framework" as tag. Hereis the deal: you do not use business objects for groups as groups have no functionality anyway and are pure read only projections.

Go SQL (either direct or with a capable LINQ provider). GROUP BY is a SQL Command you may want to read up on.

If oyu need repeatable read, then a materialized view on the server may work, or inserting the data into another table for fast access. Depends  a lot on the usage pattern. And make sure you actually have hardware capable enough for your required usage (which I agree many people will never understand). Given proper hardware (Exadata shines here, but it start i thin kat a quarter million USD or so per cluster) you can pull of billion row aggregations in nearly real time.

Comment: WOW, @TomTom -- thank you for giving an example of your database size and performance. This will also be the size of my database as well, and I was really having doubts until I read this. Btw, are you using EntityFramework in your application? If so, how do you handle this giant table and also how are you able to support such a large db hardware and SQL version wise (if you know). Is the table partitioned? Thanks! (Just a pointer to resources for such large database schema would be perfect...thanks again)